# How can I find all possible sums and differences of numbers in a vector?

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

Let's say I have a vector called numbers.
Numbers = {1, 5, 6, 8}. (A possibility I have though of is to double the size of the vector and include all the negative numbers, but I still don't have a good solution to find all the possible sums.)

Possible solutions:

4 = 5 - 1

1 = 1

19 = 8 + 6 + 5

I want the search to stop when I've found a number I will be looking for, but my main issue is just to find all of the different sums.

This is very similar to the subset sum problem but I haven't really found a solution that I can understand / that includes negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming.

Let `(a_0, ..., a_{n-1})` be your array of numbers.
Let `A(k)` be the set of all possible sums/differences of `(a_0, ..., a_{k-1})`.
Then you can easily deduce `A(k)` from `A(k-1)`. Be sure that all repetitions are removed, using hash table or sorting or anything.

The point is that, if there is an upper bound `m` of the `a_i`'s, then `A(k)` contains at most `2mk + 1` elements. Thus the complexity is reduced from `O(3^n)` to something like `O(mn^2)`.

This is probably the best thing you can do: for example, if the `a_i`'s are increasing exponentially, then the size of the final result is also exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Think in the ternary representation {0, 1, 2}, you have a set of numbers, where every number can appear as positive, negative or not appear, then you could represent this posibilities as ternary {0, 1, 2} and use it with coef -> {-1, 0, 1} you can compute all combination easily.
coef -> (-1 , 0, 1)-> ternary '0' -> value '-1', ternary '1' -> value '0' and ternary 2 -> value '1'.

`Numbers -> {n0, n1, n2, .. ni}`

Ternary representation -> `(t0)*3^0 + (t1)*3^1 + (t2)*3^2 + .. + (ti)*3^i`

Coef -> `{c0 , c1, c2, .. ci}`

Result -> `C0*n0 + C1*n1 + C2*n2 + .. + Ci*ni`

An example:

`Numbers = {1, 5, 6, 8}`

Total combinations -> `3^4 = 81`

combination number (c) ∈ [0 , 80].

f.e: `c = 79` -> `2221(ternary)`

Ternary (reverse) `{1, 2, 2, 2}` to coef `{0, 1, 1, 1}`

result (79d/2221t): `0*1 + 1*5 + 1*6 + 1*8 = 19`

To calculate all combinations, you must to calculate this steps in a loop `(i -> 0 .. 3^4)`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up solving it with dynamic programming and the subset sum way, but thanks for the help I see how I can find all the sums now.